# Is there a way to find a world position of a uniSWF MovieClip in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flash

I haven't found a solution in API

http://uniswf.com/home/apiReference/version/1.1.0

localToGlobal only converts to stage space. It doesn't change even if the transform holding the calling movieclip moves.